# Rotate a square in OpenGl

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-compat

I am trying to draw a square with a line in between. So essentially it is two triangles with different colors combined to form a square. How would I go about rotating this square by 90 degrees?

```
 void Square(float xPos, float yPos, float length){
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
       glColor3d(1,1,1);
       glVertex2d(xPos + length, yPos);
       glVertex2d(xPos, yPos);
       glVertex2d(xPos , yPos + length);
       glColor3d(0,0,0);
       glVertex2d(xPos + length, yPos + length);
    glEnd();
}
```

I have tried using glRotatef() in this function to rotate it by 90 degrees but it would still give me the same square each time.

Comment: I mean… if you rotate a square by 90 degrees, it'll still be a square.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TruchetTiling.html. My square has a filled triangle which will make it look different after rotation. Hopefully this helps explain better what I am trying to do.

Comment: I don't see any `glRotatef` in your function. Please show what you tried, don't just describe it. Apart from that, you really shouldn't be using legacy OpenGL anyways.

Comment: Legacy OpenGL is just fine for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to rotate it like this:

```
glPushMatrix();
  glRotatef(90.0f, 0, 0, 1);
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    ...
  glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```